# Why "os.path.join" and "os.path.dirname(__file__)" return different separator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner.
My system is win10 Pro,and I use python3.X.

I use this code to test function "os.path.join()" and "os.path.dirname()".

```
import os
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dateConfig.ini"))
```

The output is:

> E:/test_opencv\dateConfig.ini

I found os.path.join() use "/",but os.path.dirname() use "\",why?

If I want to use the same separator,all is '/' or '\',what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because `__file__` contains the script name as passed in argument.

If you run

```
python E:/test_opencv/myscript.py
```

then `__file__` contains exactly the argument passed to `python`. (Windows has `os.altsep` as `/`, because it can use this alternate separator)

A good way of fixing that is to use `os.path.normpath` to replace the alternate separator by the official separator, remove double separators, ...

```
print(os.path.join(os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),"dateConfig.ini"))
```

Normalizing the path can be useful when running legacy Windows commands that don't support slashes/consider them as option switches. If you just use the path to pass to `open`, you don't need that.

Comment: Thank you,sir!This is useful.